# How to make font size equal in iOS and android?

Tags: android, ios, uifont

I am uploading text with specific font size from my iOS Device and I want to display in android with same text as it is displaying in iOS.For that I have to match font in both platforms.Is there any specific way to convert font size from iOS to android and android to iOS, so that in both platform text should be looking same from any platform?

Comment: @Patel did you try giving custom fonts to both platforms and having size same?

Comment: Kindly share you are trying to achieve as a code or as an image, i know your question is straightforward but SO is not coding machine.